# Replicate via pglogical on a hot_standby setup

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, database-administration, pgpool

I am running two databases (PostgreSQL 9.5.7) in a master/slave setup. My application is connecting to a pgpool instance which routes to the master database (and slave for read only queries).

Now I am trying to scale out some data to another read-only database instance containing only a few tables.
This works perfectly using **pglogical** directly on the master database.

**However** if the master transitions to slave for some reason, pglogical can't replicate any longer because the node is in standby.

Tried following things:

1. **subscribed on the slave since it's less likely to go down, or overheated:** Can't replicate on standby node.
2. **subscribed via pgpool server:** pgpool doesn't accept replication connections.
3. **subscribed to both servers:** pglogical config gets replicated along, so can't give them different node names.

The only thing I can think of now is to write my own tcp proxy which regularly checks for the state of the server to which I can subscribe to.

Is there any other/easier way I can solve this ?
Am I using the wrong tools perhaps ?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using ?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.7.

Comment: You're not the first to have this issue... You might find this helpfull: https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical/issues/83

Comment: Thnx. I think I can assume, based on the github thread, that there is no solution but to wait for PostgreSQL 10 or use routing rules ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seems that there are no solutions for this problem just yet.
Since the data in my logically replicated database is not changing fast, there is no harm if the replication stops for a moment.

Actions on failover could be:

- Re-subscribe to the promoted master.
- or promote standby node back to master after failover.